# Clean history (recent folder) in Android 5+ directory tree picker (ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, storage-access-framework

Directory tree picker created by

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
...
```

on Android 5+ saves all picked directories history to the `Recent` folder:

[image]

...

**Is there a way how to erase this history?**

Comment: Have you tried from `DocumentsProvider`?

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski No. You mean instead of using the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recents history is saved in a database which is located:

```
/data/data/com.android.documentsui/databases/recents.db
```

So it's not accessible to the other apps, unless the device is rooted.

There is a `ContentProvider` ([RecentsProvider](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/packages/DocumentsUI/src/com/android/documentsui/RecentsProvider.java)) that manages the database but unfortunately it isn't [exported](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/packages/DocumentsUI/AndroidManifest.xml#L50-L53), so only applications that have the same user ID (UID) as the provider will have access to it [[1]](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#exported).

There is also a `BroadcastReceiver` ([PackageReceiver](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/packages/DocumentsUI/src/com/android/documentsui/PackageReceiver.java)) that controls the `ContentProvider` and purge the recents but unfortunately it only receives `ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED`[[2]](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED) and `ACTION_PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED` [[3]](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED). Both the intent are protected and they can only be sent by the system.

**tl;dr** Unfortunately you can't clean the recents. The only viable solution is to clear the whole data of Documents app, but in this case every settings will be lost.

Comment: Thanks. It's a complex answer to my question.